# Java reflection get constructor from class name failed

Tags: java, class, reflection, constructor

I've this code snippet:

```
class You{
    public You(String s){}
}

public static void main(String[] args)  throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Constructor[] constructors = You.class.getConstructors();
    for(Constructor constructor: constructors){
        Class[] parameterTypes = constructor.getParameterTypes();
        for(Class c: parameterTypes){
            System.out.println(c.getName());//print java.lang.String
        }
    }
    Constructor constructor =
            You.class.getConstructor(String.class);//NoSuchMethodException?
}
```

This is quite old, when I print the constructors, it has one constructor with `java.lang.String` as parameter. But when I tried to `You.class.getConstructor` it says no constructor with `String.class` as parameter.

I'm using **java1.8** on mac. Would you help to explain and how to fix?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is `You` and inner class?

Comment: This example works perfectly for me. Can you share a more exact example? This snippet is probably missing some key factor from your actual code

Comment: [Here's the code working on Ideone.](https://ideone.com/kysETf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll delete this answer if it's not the case, but it looks like `You` is an inner class, and I suspect your actual code looks something like this:

```
public class Foo {

    class You {
        public You(String s){}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Constructor[] constructors = You.class.getConstructors();

        for (Constructor constructor: constructors) {
            Class[] parameterTypes = constructor.getParameterTypes();

            for (Class c: parameterTypes){
                System.out.println(c.getName());//print java.lang.String
            }
        }

        Constructor constructor =
            You.class.getConstructor(String.class);//NoSuchMethodException?
    }
}
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) of `Class#getConstructor`:

> If this Class object represents an inner class declared in a non-static context, the formal parameter types include the explicit enclosing instance as the first parameter.

For this reason, you'll have to use the following instead:

```
Constructor constructor = You.class.getConstructor(Foo.class, String.class);
```

But obviously replace `Foo` with the name of your enclosing class.

Answer (score 2):

If `You` is really an inner class then you need to get its constructor a little bit differently.

Here is the Javadoc snippet from [Class.getConstructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-)

> If this Class object represents an inner class declared in a
>   non-static context, the formal parameter types include the explicit
>   enclosing instance as the first parameter.

This means that you need to also pass enclosing class to the `Class.getConstructor` call.

Here is an example (includes how to create an instance of inner class from its `Constructor`):

```
public class Test {
    class You{
        public You(String s){}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Constructor constructor =
                You.class.getConstructor(Test.class, String.class);//NoSuchMethodException?

        try {
            You you = constructor.newInstance(new Test(), "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getConstructors()` returns visable constructors. Try `getDeclaredConstructors()` or make the class `public`.