# java reflection constructor.newInstance gives "wrong number of arguments"

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

How to fix my code below?

```
package mypackage;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class testReflection {
    public class You {
        public You(String s) {
        }

        public void f(String s, int i) {
            System.out.println(i + 100);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Constructor constructor =
                You.class.getConstructor(testReflection.class, String.class);
        try {
            You y = (You)constructor.newInstance("xzy");//Exception!!!!
            System.out.println("ok");
            y.f("xyz",2);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception message is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at mypackage.testReflection.main
```

Comment: There was already an answer to your very recent question on how to get inner class constructor and create a new instance with it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229272/812787

Comment: You specifically *listed* `testReflection.class` in your `getConstructor` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is on this line (the constructor takes 2 parameters):

```
Constructor constructor =
            You.class.getConstructor(testReflection.class, String.class);
```

You need to send an instance of `testReflection` to `newInstance()`:

```
testReflection outerObject = new testReflection();
You y = (You)constructor.newInstance(outerObject,  "xzy");
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)) of `Constructor#newInstance`:

> If the constructor's declaring class is an inner class in a non-static context, the first argument to the constructor needs to be the enclosing instance; see section 15.9.3 of The Java™ Language Specification.

Because `You` is an inner class, you need an instance of its enclosing class, `testReflection`, to create an instance of `You`. To do this, you can use the following:

```
You y = (You) constructor.newInstance(new testReflection(), "xzy");
```

I also recommend changing your class name to `TestReflection` as that follows the proper naming conventions.